# Code Chef RAINBOW Palindrome

Tags: algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, clojure, palindrome

#### [Problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/RAINBOWA)

> Determine whether an array is "Rainbow", i.e. it has the following
>   structure:
>
> - First *a*<sub>1</sub> elements equal 1.
> - Next *a*<sub>2</sub> elements equal 2.
> - Next *a*<sub>3</sub> elements equal 3.
> - Next *a*<sub>4</sub> elements equal 4.
> - Next *a*<sub>5</sub> elements equal 5.
> - Next *a*<sub>6</sub> elements equal 6.
> - Next *a*<sub>7</sub> elements equal 7.
> - Next *a*<sub>6</sub> elements equal 6.
> - Next *a*<sub>5</sub> elements equal 5.
> - Next *a*<sub>4</sub> elements equal 4.
> - Next *a*<sub>3</sub> elements equal 3.
> - Next *a*<sub>2</sub> elements equal 2.
> - Next *a*<sub>1</sub> elements equal 1.
>
> *a<sub>i</sub>* can be any positive integer. There are no other elements in array.

#### Solution

```
(defn palindrome? [items]
  "Efficient algorithm: loops through only (array-size/2)"
  (loop [i 0
         j (-> items count dec)]
    (cond (>= i j)
          true
          (not= (nth items i) 
                (nth items j))
          false
          :else
          (recur (inc i) (dec j)))))

(let [test-cases-count (Integer/parseInt (read-line))
      test-cases       (for [i (range test-cases-count)]
                         (let [nums-count (read-line)
                               nums-temp (-> (read-line) (clojure.string/split #"\s+"))
                               nums (map #(Integer/parseInt %) nums-temp)]
                           nums))]
  (for [t test-cases]
    (if (palindrome? t)
      (println "Yes")
      (println "No"))))
```

Not able to figure out how to optimize this.

Comment: You didn't solve the stated problem. Consider this vector: 9 8 9. Yes, it is a palindrome. No, it's not a Rainbow. You don't range check for 1..7. You don't enforce monotonically increasing (until middle). You don't require starting with 1 and ending (in middle) with 7.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn palindrome? [items]
  "Efficient algorithm: loops through only (array-size/2)"
     ...
         (not= (nth items i) 
               (nth items j))
```

`nth` is efficient on vectors and other things that support random indexing. On sequences, which you're passing in right now, it's `O(n)` *per lookup* since it has to walk the list.

Changing your test cases to use vectors should help (use [`mapv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) instead of `map`):

```
(let [...
      nums (mapv #(Integer/parseInt %) nums-temp)]
```

---

```
(def example (concat (range 1000) (reverse (range 1000))))
(count example)   ; 2000
(def examplev (vec example))
(count examplev)  ; 2000

(dotimes [_ 3] (time (palindrome? example)))
; "Elapsed time: 45.167334 msecs"
; "Elapsed time: 44.568282 msecs"
; "Elapsed time: 45.304136 msecs"

(dotimes [_ 3] (time (palindrome? examplev)))
; "Elapsed time: 0.317649 msecs"
; "Elapsed time: 0.272229 msecs"
; "Elapsed time: 0.30044 msecs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit `true`s and `false`s are usually a code smell in Clojure. Your `palindrome?` function reads better as

```
(defn palindrome? [items]
  (loop [i 0, j (-> items count dec)]
    (or (>= i j)
        (and (= (nth items i) (nth items j))
             (recur (inc i) (dec j))))))
```

... which probably produces identical code.

You could also drop the `nth` calls, as a vector works as an indexing function. This would trap attempts to supply an ordinary sequence.

Alternatively, We could use sequence functions:

```
(defn palindrome? [v]
  (let [half-count (-> v count (quot 2))]
    (every? identity (map = (subvec v 0 half-count) (sequence (rseq v))))))
```

I think this would be slower, though I haven't tested it.